# Linux Kernel's __is_constexpr Macro

Tags: c, linux-kernel, macros, language-lawyer

How does the `__is_constexpr(x)` macro of the Linux Kernel work? What is its purpose? When was it introduced? Why was it introduced?

```
/*
 * This returns a constant expression while determining if an argument is
 * a constant expression, most importantly without evaluating the argument.
 * Glory to Martin Uecker <Martin.Uecker@med.uni-goettingen.de>
 */
#define __is_constexpr(x) \
        (sizeof(int) == sizeof(*(8 ? ((void *)((long)(x) * 0l)) : (int *)8)))
```

---

For a **discussion on different approaches** to solve the same problem, see instead: [Detecting Integer Constant Expressions in Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480442/detecting-integer-constant-expressions-in-macros)

Comment: I don't think it's common knowledge that `sizeof(void)` isn't allowed by the standard… The relevant passages are [§6.5.3.4 ¶ 1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p1) (`void` is an incomplete type) and [§6.2.5 ¶ 19](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p19) (no incomplete types to `sizeof`, which should be obvious).

Comment: You did not make it clear that "Explain Macro which tests for Integer Constant Expression" was [your own recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480442/detecting-integer-constant-expressions-in-macros). Is this of any practical use, or academic chewing gum? Nice answer to your own question.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Thank you! This macro was being discussed a few days ago in the LKML as a possible solution for a problem regarding VLAs in the kernel, so it is clear that it has a practical use -- specially if it ends up in the kernel tree.

Comment: I'm with Linus about this. And as this macro is also compiler-specific, why not use a builtin which would be clear?

Comment: @Olaf: Linus Torvalds is actually praising the solution. As for built-ins, there isn't one for this -- that is why this macro was suggested!

Comment: If that's true, I retract my agreement. The citation in your question reads as if he dislikes it. And what is the problem with `__builtin_constant_p`? While it might not be strictly determining the standard's _constant-expression_, to me it looks like what is actually wanted. Anyway, we are not a discussion forum and I'll leave it at this.

Comment: not sure how anyone finds the question unclear

Comment: @Olaf `__builtin_constant_p` tests whether its argument is a "constant expression", not whether its argument is an "integer constant expression" (for the C-standardese definitions of both terms); the use case for this macro requires a check for an "integer constant expression". Yes, the kernel devs should ask the GCC devs to add `__builtin_integer_constant_p`, but only for readability's sake; it would be no more portable than relying on the GCC extension that defines `sizeof(void)`.

Comment: @zwol: I did not say the one builtin is sufficient. But you can use a second builtin to determine the type. With C11, you could use `_Generic`.

Comment: @Olaf I was responding only to your "what is the problem with `__builtin_constant_p`", not to any other aspect of this discussion.

Comment: For what contexts would one use this macro (as opposed to __builtin_integer_constant_p) other than for asserting that something that should be constant, actually is?  Having a compiler treat `sizeof (void)` as a number which differs from `sizeof (int)` may allow the code to output a better message than having it simply error-out on `sizeof (void)`, but if the intention is that code not compile if something isn't constant that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: `__builtin_constant_p` does not appear to be guaranteed to be a constant expression, at least not on all GCC versions.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Linux Kernel's `__is_constexpr` macro

### Introduction

The `__is_constexpr(x)` macro can be found in Linux Kernel's [include/kernel/kernel.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/kernel.h?id=3c8ba0d61d04ced9f8d9ff93977995a9e4e96e91#n814):

```
/*
 * This returns a constant expression while determining if an argument is
 * a constant expression, most importantly without evaluating the argument.
 * Glory to Martin Uecker <Martin.Uecker@med.uni-goettingen.de>
 */
#define __is_constexpr(x) \
        (sizeof(int) == sizeof(*(8 ? ((void *)((long)(x) * 0l)) : (int *)8)))
```

It was introduced during the merge window for Linux Kernel v4.17, [commit 3c8ba0d61d04](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=3c8ba0d61d04ced9f8d9ff93977995a9e4e96e91) on 2018-04-05; although the discussions around it started a month before.

The macro is notable for taking advantage of subtle details of the C standard: the *conditional operator*'s rules for determining its returned type (6.5.15.6) and the definition of a *null pointer constant* (6.3.2.3.3).

In addition, it relies on `sizeof(void)` being allowed (and different than `sizeof(int)`), which is a [GNU C extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html).

---

### How does it work?

The macro's body is:

```
(sizeof(int) == sizeof(*(8 ? ((void *)((long)(x) * 0l)) : (int *)8)))
```

Let's focus on this part:

```
((void *)((long)(x) * 0l))
```

<sub>*Note: the `(long)(x)` cast is [intended](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/21/775) to allow `x` to have pointer types and to avoid warnings on `u64` types on 32-bit platforms. However, this detail is not important for understanding the key points of the macro.*</sub>

If `x` **is** an *integer constant expression* (6.6.6), then it follows that `((long)(x) * 0l)` is an *integer constant expression* of value `0`. Therefore, `(void *)((long)(x) * 0l)` is a *null pointer constant* (6.3.2.3.3):

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type **void ***, is called a *null pointer constant*

If `x` is **not** an *integer constant expression*, then `(void *)((long)(x) * 0l)` is not a *null pointer constant*, **regardless of its value**.

Knowing that, we can see what happens afterwards:

```
8 ? ((void *)((long)(x) * 0l)) : (int *)8
```

<sub>*Note: the second `8` literal is [intended](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/21/775) to avoid compiler warnings about creating pointers to unaligned addresses. The first `8` literal could simply be `1`. However, these details are not important for understanding the key points of the macro.*</sub>

The key here is that the *conditional operator* returns a **different type** depending on whether one of the operands is a *null pointer constant* (6.5.15.6):

> [...] if one operand is a null pointer constant, the result has the type of the other operand; otherwise, one operand is a pointer to **void** or a qualified version of **void**, in which case the result type is a pointer to an appropriately qualified version of **void**.

So, if `x` **was** an *integer constant expression*, then the second operand is a *null pointer constant* and therefore the type of the expression is the type of the third operand, which is a pointer to `int`.

**Otherwise**, the second operand is a pointer to `void` and thus the type of the expression is a pointer to `void`.

Therefore, we end up with two possibilities:

```
sizeof(int) == sizeof(*((int *) (NULL))) // if `x` was an integer constant expression
sizeof(int) == sizeof(*((void *)(....))) // otherwise
```

According to the [GNU C extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html), `sizeof(void) == 1`. Therefore, if `x` was an *integer constant expression*, the result of the macro is `1`; otherwise, `0`.

Moreover, since we are only comparing for equality two `sizeof` expressions, the result is itself another *integer constant expression* (6.6.3, 6.6.6):

> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.
>
> An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, **sizeof** expressions whose results are integer constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the **sizeof** operator.

Therefore, in summary, the `__is_constexpr(x)` macro returns an *integer constant expression* of value `1` if the argument is an integer constant expression. Otherwise, it returns an *integer constant expression* of value `0`.

---

### Why was it introduced?

The macro came to be [during the effort](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/7/621) to remove all [Variable Length Arrays (VLAs)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) from the Linux kernel.

In order to facilitate so, it was desirable to enable [GCC's `-Wvla` warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) kernel-wide; so that all instances of VLAs were flagged by the compiler.

When the warning was enabled, it turned out that GCC reported many cases of arrays being VLAs which was not intended to be so. For instance in [fs/btrfs/tree-checker.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16/source/fs/btrfs/tree-checker.c#L344):

```
#define BTRFS_NAME_LEN 255
#define XATTR_NAME_MAX 255

char namebuf[max(BTRFS_NAME_LEN, XATTR_NAME_MAX)];
```

A developer may expect that `max(BTRFS_NAME_LEN, XATTR_NAME_MAX)` was resolved to `255` and therefore it should be treated as a standard array (i.e. non-VLA). However, this depends on what the `max(x, y)` macro expands to.

The key issue is that GCC generates VLA-code if the array's size is not an *(integer) constant expression* as defined by the C standard. For instance:

```
#define not_really_constexpr ((void)0, 100)

int a[not_really_constexpr];
```

According to the C90 standard, `((void)0, 100)` is **not** a *constant expression* (6.6), due to the *comma operator* being used (6.6.3). In this case, GCC opts to issue VLA code, [even when it knows the size is a compile-time constant](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/16/349). Clang, in contrast, does not.

Since the `max(x, y)` macro in the kernel was not a constant expression, GCC triggered the warnings and generated VLA code where kernel developers did not intend it.

Therefore, a few kernel developers tried to develop alternative versions of the `max` and other macros to avoid the warnings and the VLA code. Some attempts tried to leverage [GCC's `__builtin_constant_p` builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), but no approach worked with all the versions of GCC that the kernel supported at the time (`gcc >= 4.4`).

At some point, Martin Uecker [proposed](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/20/805) a particularly clever approach that did not use builtins ([taking inspiration](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/27/378) from [glibc's tgmath.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=math/tgmath.h;h=a709a59d0fa1168ef03349561169fc5bd27d65aa;hb=d8742dd82f6a00601155c69bad3012e905591e1f)):

```
#define ICE_P(x) (sizeof(int) == sizeof(*(1 ? ((void*)((x) * 0l)) : (int*)1)))
```

While the approach uses a GCC extension, [it was nevertheless well-received](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/20/845) and was used as the key idea behind the `__is_constexpr(x)` macro which appeared in the kernel after a few iterations with other developers. The macro was used then to implement the `max` macro and other macros that are required to be constant expressions in order to avoid GCC generating VLA code.

Comment: Citing the standard will not really help here, as the behaviour contains implementation-defined and possibly (I'm not in the mood to verify) undefined behaviour. It's just bad coding style.

Comment: @Olaf: I am not sure I follow your logic. Implementation-defined, unspecified and undefined behavior are concepts defined and used by the standards themselves -- so citing a standard is actually the proper way to know whether something is implementation-defined, undefined or something else. In any case, `sizeof(void)` is just not a valid C program since it violates a constraint (6.2.5.19, 6.5.3.4.1). As for the coding style, it cannot be "bad", since there aren't any well-known "good" portable ways of doing this in C89 (if any at all!).

Comment: "there aren't any well-known "good" portable ways" - exactly my point. And if you stick to IDB/UB (the latter just working on a specific implementation) anyway: K.I.S.S.

Comment: @Olaf: There is no way of "keeping it simple" if there is no other way of doing it. In any case, this question is about explaining the macro above as a complement to the linked question -- so please refer to that one instead to discuss or propose better ways of achieving this.