# Why is the ternary operator behaving _weirdly_ in that syntax?

Tags: c, ternary-operator

I was reading an answer from Torvald in the linux mailing ([here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/20/845)) about a macro that could be used to determine if an expression is an ICE. Here is the macro:

```
#define ICE_P(x) (sizeof(int) == sizeof(*(1 ? ((void*)((x) * 0l)) : (int*)1)))
```

So Torvald explains why it's doing what it's supposed to do and at what point he writes:

> the rule is that if one of the sides of a ternary operation with
>   pointers is NULL, the end result is the other type

I was perplex about that statement so I tested the behaviour with the following code:

```
printf("%ld\n", sizeof(*(1 ? NULL : (int *)1)));
printf("%ld\n", sizeof(*(1 ? NULL : (char *)1)));
```

To my surprise this (when compiled with either gcc or clang) prints the following output:

```
4
1
```

Now after a bit of thinking I believe what's happening here is that gcc is implicitly casting NULL to either an int * or char * and then returning that NULL with those types, thus giving the previous answer.

Is that the case or am I misunderstanding what's going on?

Comment: also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481217/explain-macro-which-tests-for-integer-constant-expression there are a lot of SO questions about this strange ICE_P macro. Look them up.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I did research if there was anything about ternary operators and pointers but did not think about searching the macro itself -.- indeed the second link you pointed to answers my question; thanks!

Comment: yes, I read the accepted answer (with some aspirin on the side :)) and I decided to close as duplicate. Glad that we agree.

Comment: your question is simpler & shows some research, so a useful duplicate (to me it is)

Comment: i'll take that as a compliment :D thanks :)