# Is lowercase null valid in C++?

Tags: c++, standards, std

Is there any lowercase `null` in any version of C++ language specification?

#### Background:

I was asked in an interview "Which of the following pointer initializations are valid?", and I filled the form something like:

```
// valid
    int* p1 = 0;
    int* p2 = 2-2;
    int* p6 = new int;
// invalid
    int* p3 = 1; 

    int z = 0;
    int* p4 = z;
// ???
    int* p5 = null;
```

Comment: not that im aware of, just NULL and nullptr

Comment: Nothing stops you from making a `null` macro, just like how `NULL` is a macro.

Comment: @Top-Master int* p5 = null; can be valid or invalid depending on how null is defined.:)

Comment: @blaze Hopefully an idea of engineering sanity would stop you from doing that.

Comment: @Top-Master And my advice: never do assignments in an interview. Interview is not an exam.:)

Comment: Strictly speaking, `int* p2 = 2-2;` is not valid either.

Comment: I would avoid the lowercase `null` just from a readability standpoint. When someone is scanning your code the will either be looking for `NULL` or `nullptr`. `null` would just provide a double-head-turn or be skimmed over entirely.

Comment: @StoryTeller Does C++ make it invalid? It's perfectly valid C.

Comment: `int* p4 = z;` also depending on what the `z` variable is

Comment: @Raffallo `int z = 0;
    int* p4 = z;` is a single example. `z` is an `int`.

Comment: @melpomene - Very sneakily so, it does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55780426/implementing-the-linux-kernels-is-constexpr-ice-p-macro-in-pure-c

Comment: @lubgr true that - in C++ even using `NULL` is questionable when there's `nullptr`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Is there any lowercase `null` in any version of the C++ language specification?

No.

Comment: Well, yeah, that does it.

Comment: It would be better with a reference-link or something, but still, this seems to be the right answer.

Comment: @Top-Master Yeah, this requires proving a negative. The evidence of absence here is the lack of any section in the C++ standard that mentions `null` as a valid token. So really, "no" is pretty much the perfect answer IMO. :-)

Comment: @Top-Master The only guarantee you have is that advanced C++ programmers looked at this answer and agree due to the lack of comments :)

Answer (score 8):

A one word answer would be NO.

try the below code

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int *p = null;
    int *q = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the below error on compilation:

error: ‘null’ was not declared in this scope

Which is self explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is written in some of the header files. NULL is the predefined macro in those header files such as **

> **-> #define NULL 0**

**. Hence we can only define with uppercase "NULL" to avoid the compilation termination.

However, if you wish for lower case null, you can do so by defining the new macro or make charges in predefined macro in the header file. but be careful before you want to make these changes.